# Split large tiff into multiple pages with correct borders

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I test this on my windows machine, but in the end it should run here:

```
identify -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2018-09-28 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

---

I have a long tiff (1700x96274) and I split it into multiple tiff pages with this command:

```
magick convert large.tiff -crop 1700x2300 -page A4 cropped_%d.tiff
```

But then I'm cutting text or images very often. What I want is a smart border with mostly white, e.g. between 2200-2400.

How can cut the image into multiple images with detecting white (mostly) spaces and use them as variable border?

Comment: Can you show a small piece of your image and explain what you want to avoid or add? ImageMagick does not have a smart crop that will avoid text. Also not that in ImageMagick 7, you should use simply magick and not magick convert. Also you probably should add +repage after a crop, unless you want to put the pieces back together later.

Comment: Tnaks for the hint with repage;-)
I dont want to just do that on one image, thats why I think it is not important to give you some example tiff. I want to print the tiff to paper, e.g. you print a html page. I have a html2Tiff, thats why it could be 1700x90000 for any website you can scroll down very often.